# Last part of the sentence "the most"

Tags: grammar

"I want everybody to come to the party, but I want James to come **the most**".
The last part of the sentence "The most". Does it works as adverb of degree?

Comment: Yes: a degree adjunct (your adverb). Note that the determinative "the" functions here as a modifier of "most".

Comment: Yeah, it's effectively an adverb on "most".  The usage is a hair non-formal, but common in the US.

Comment: How would this sound? _I want all of them, but I want James the most_. Seems perfectly normal to me. _Want_ can take an infinitive complement, so it's no different with _want James to come_. The only problem might be the long distance between _want_ and _the most_.

Comment: A degree modifier in the VP "want James to come the most".

Answer (score 1):

*the most* is acting as a *comparative adverb*, *a superlative adverb*.

See

> [British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/comparative-and-superlative-adverbs)
> We make comparative and superlative adverbs using the same rules as for comparative and superlative adjectives. For example:
> *Jill works fast.   >   faster  >   fastest*
> When we intensify a superlative adverb, we often put "the" in front of the adverb:
> *In our office, Jill works by far the hardest
>
> Of the three brothers, Brian easily runs the fastest.*

Similarly in your text. "*I want James to come/to come more/to come most/to come the most*" compares the degree or intensity of wanting James rather than wanting others.